# How to refactor a long Google Sheet formula or convert to a custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula I want to use in a Google Sheet. However, it is quite long. Plus its really tedious having to change the cells.

Here is the formula

```
=IF(E10=5, 1,
  IF(E10=10, 2,
    IF(E10=15, 3,
      IF(E10=20, 4,
        IF(E10=25, 6,
          IF(E10=50, 12,
            IF(E10=100, 24)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The objective is to compare 2 columns. One will have a multiple of 5. As you can see . The next column (Where the formula is) changes depending on what number is in the previous column and outputs a specific number.

Can you please turn this into a function that i can use instead of typing out this huge formula?

**EDIT**
In researching for an answer to this I tried looking into other premade functions however none of them will do what I need especially to specific numbers/cells. I have also tried to code a function myself by butchering another function I have in place and by copy-pasting the formula in. However, my knowledge of code is very limited (non-existent) and whatever I was doing was not working which is why I have asked for help here.

Comment: I have done the edit. My apologies.

Comment: Show your attempts to write a code

Comment: Why can't you just divide it? `=E10/5` or `=FLOOR(E10/5)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula

```
=SWITCH(E10,5,1,10,2,15,3,20,4,25,6,50,12,100,24)
```

instead of yours.

`VLOOKUP` is also smart

```
=VLOOKUP(E10,K4:L10,2)
```

[image]